# Prevent ta.crossover when its a newday

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[image]

As you can the * blue shape is plotted when we have

```
bool isLongTrade = ta.crossover(close, EMA)
plotshape(isLongTrade)
```

I tried using Timewindow where it won't check for the first candle but  did not work.

cross over is for closing of candle above 200 EMA, and when there is a GAP up in the new day it should not count as crossover.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if it is a new day and add this to your condition with the **not** operator.

```
is_new_day = bool(timeframe.change("D"))
bool isLongTrade = ta.crossover(close, EMA) and not is_new_day 
plotshape(isLongTrade)
```

Comment: `bool isLongTrade = ta.crossover(close, EMA)

if isNewDay
    isLongTrade := false`

i did this